# Left exterior multiplication is exact sequence

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I'm been trying to solve the following problem  form Warner ex 2.15:

# 15: Let $\eta \in V$. Prove that the composition

$$
\Lambda^p(V) \xrightarrow{\eta \wedge}{} \Lambda^{p+1}(V)\xrightarrow{\eta \wedge}{} \Lambda^{p+2}(V)
$$
of left exterior multiplication by $\eta$ with itself is an exact sequence.

Solution: First, let $\omega \in \Lambda^p(V)$, we observe that 
$$
[(\eta \wedge ) \circ (\eta \wedge)](\omega)=(\eta \wedge \eta)\wedge \omega=0 \Rightarrow \ker (\eta \wedge) \supset im (\eta \wedge).
$$
Second, the hardest part is to prove that $\ker (\eta \wedge) \subset im (\eta \wedge):$ We must prove that if $(\eta\wedge)(\omega)=0$ for $\omega \in \Lambda^{p+1}(V)$, then there exists $\zeta \in \Lambda^p(V)$ such that $(\eta \wedge)(\zeta)=\omega:$ any clue/hint for this part will be wonderful.

Following your hints. I establish the following

Extending $\eta$ to a basis $\eta_1,...,\eta_n$ for $V^{*}$ with $\eta_1=\eta$ and set 
$$
\omega=\sum_{J}c_J\eta_{J}
$$
where $J$ runs over all strictly ascending multi-indices $1\leq j_1<\cdots <j_p\leq n$. In the sum 
$$
\eta \wedge \omega=\sum_{J}\eta \wedge \eta_{J} 
$$
all terms $\eta \wedge \eta_{J}$ with $j_1=1$  vanish since $\eta=\eta_1$. Hence,
$$
0=\eta \wedge \omega=\sum_{j_1 \neq 1} c_J \eta \wedge \eta_J.
$$
Since $\{\eta \wedge \eta_J\}$ for $j_1 \neq 1$ is a subset of a basis for $\Lambda^{p+1}(V)$, it is linearly independent, and so all $c_J$ are $0$ if $j_1 \neq 1$. Therefore,
$$
\omega= \sum_{j_1=1}c_J\eta_J =\eta \wedge \underbrace{\left( \sum_{j_1=1}c_J \eta_{j_2}\wedge \cdots \eta_{j_p} \right)}_{\zeta}.
$$
Thereby, $\ker (\eta \wedge)=im (\eta \wedge)$ i.e., it is an exact sequence.

Thank you so much for your time. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Try extending $\eta$ to a basis for $V$ and see what the condition $\eta\wedge\omega = 0$ looks like in this basis.

Comment: I know that if $\eta \wedge \omega=0$, it means that $\eta$ and $\omega$ are linearly independent. So, I'm able to express one in terms of the other one (linear combinations). Is it right ?

Comment: I think you mean to say that if $\omega\in V$, then the condition $\omega\wedge\eta = 0$ is equivalent to $\omega,\eta$ being linearly *dependent*. That's a good starting point  because it proves the case $p=0$. To get a feel for the general case, extend $\eta$ to a basis $\eta = \eta_1, \dots ,\eta_n$ for $V$ (assuming $\eta\neq 0$) and consider $\omega = \eta_{i_0} \wedge \cdots \wedge \eta_{i_p}$. Can you see what the condition $\eta\wedge\omega$ looks like here?

Comment: The parenthetical "assuming $\eta\neq0$" in the comment by @AlexK is important. The result is false if $\eta=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I got the idea. I'll write down soon ^.^